JMS Serializer and Enum
This code snippet is from the documentation
    # config.yml
    jms_serializer:
        profiler: %kernel.debug%
        enum_support: true # PHP 8.1 Enums support, false by default for backward compatibility
        default_value_property_reader_support: true # PHP 8.0 Constructor Promotion default value support, false by default for backward compatibility
        twig_enabled: 'default' # on which instance is twig enabled
        handlers:
            datetime:
                default_format: "Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP" # ATOM
                default_timezone: "UTC" # defaults to whatever timezone set in php.ini or via date_default_timezone_set
            array_collection:
                initialize_excluded: false
            symfony_uid:
                default_format: "canonical"
                cdata: true

I'm trying to set this up in a project on Symfony.
jms_serializer:
    enum_support: true
    default_value_property_reader_support: true

I create serializer with DI SerializerInterface
public function __construct(
    private SerializerInterface $jmsSerializer
) {
}

And when I try to deserialize json< I catch error: The provided class "App\\...\\Enumeration\\DocumentDescribeTypeEnum\" is an enum, and cannot be instantiated
How to fix it?

I think it'd be helpful to see the (de)serialization config (annotations, YAML, whatever) for your class.  However, the following may point you—and others—in the right direction.
I wanted to deserialize enums, too, and saw the same error as you—at one time or another.  We're using JMS Serializer as a standalone library and our config is in YAML.
In my case, I needed to do two things:

Enable support for enums, something like:

$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()
    ->enableEnumSupport()  // <-- This is the key bit
    ->build()
;


Correctly configure the property, something like:

Fully\Qualified\Class\Name:
    properties:
        foo:
            expose: true
            type: enum<'Fully\Qualified\Enum\Name'>  # <-- This is the key bit

N.B. At least in YAML, the quotes around the fully-qualified name of the enum are required—given what I saw in the code for JMS Serializer, I expect the same will apply if you're using annotations.
